# Filtering sqlite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Having trouble with filtering in my sqlite3 query. I am working with three tables below.

```
Table: models
id|data 
1|car
2|truck

Table: descriptions
id|model_id|colour|make
1|1|blue|accord
2|1|green|prius
3|1|red|fusion
4|1|black|civic
5|1|white|jeep
6|1|purple|jeep
7|1|brown|jeep
8|1|brown|civic

Table: banned
model_id|colour_id|colour
1|3|black|
1|15|brown|
```

The below statement is counting how many of what model (cars or trucks) are what make.

```
SELECT models.id, make, count(make) 
FROM description 
JOIN models ON models.id = descriptions.model_id 
GROUP BY models.id, descriptions.make;
```

The output would below

```
1|accord|1
1|prius|1
1|fusion|1
1|civic|2
1|jeep|3
```

However, I want to put in a qualifier that voids anything containing a banned colour/model combo, by using banned.colour.
I tried joining the table and filtering out like below, but it seems to double the count.

```
SELECT models.id, make, count(make) 
FROM description 
JOIN models ON models.id = descriptions.model_id 
JOIN banned ON banned.model_id = models.id 
WHERE NOT ( banned.colour = descriptions.colour) 
GROUP BY models.id, descriptions.make;
```

My desired output is to void the two cars that fit this qualifier from the count. The final result should below

```
1|accord|1
1|prius|1
1|fusion|1
1|jeep|2
```

How can i achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "void"?

Comment: @Shawn remove it from the count. Count everything except what matches my exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your approach . . . with a `left join` and `where` check:

```
SELECT m.id, d.make, count(*) 
FROM description d JOIN
     models m
     ON m.id = d.model_id LEFT JOIN
     banned b
     ON b.model_id = m.id AND b.colour = d.colour
WHERE b.model_id IS NULL   -- no match
GROUP BY m.id, d.make;
```

A common way to write the query would also use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT m.id, d.make, count(*) 
FROM description d JOIN
     models m
     ON m.id = d.model_id         
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM banned b
                  WHERE b.model_id = m.id AND b.colour = d.colour
                 )
GROUP BY m.id, d.make;
```

Although you can also use `NOT IN`, I highly discourage using it with  a subquery.  It will not do what you want if any of the values returned by the subquery are `NULL`.

Comment: Awesome! The `where not exists` works perfectly. How would i go upon adding another condition to this. Would just adding an `OR` after the first condition work?

Comment: @Hysii . . . An `or` or an `and`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `NOT IN` with a dependent subquery to avoid banned combinations.

```
SELECT models.id, make, count(make) 
FROM description 
JOIN models ON models.id = descriptions.model_id 
WHERE colour NOT IN (
  SELECT colour 
  FROM banned
  WHERE banned.model_id = models.id
)
GROUP BY models.id, descriptions.make;
```

The only pitfall of `NOT IN` is a possibility to have a `NULL` in the subquery result. However, I believe that it is safe if the `colour` attribute is defined as `NOT NULL` (which make sense in this case).